# how to identify elements of a list that corresponds to a criteria and apply a function

Tags: python, list, encryption, ascii

So I need a program which encrypts a text file:

```
for x in range(1):
    random_generated=(random.sample(range(33,126), 8))
    random_values=(random_generated[0:])
    print random_values
    ######using the random function to generate numbers from 33 to 126, 8 times######

    
    ascii="".join([chr(i) for i in random_values])   ###to convert numbers to ASCII characters### 
    print ascii     ###displaying to user###         ###source: stackoverflow.com################

    offset_factor=(((sum(random_generated[0:]))//8)-32)   ###to calculate the offset factor based on the generated###
    print offset_factor

    opentxt= open(filename, 'r').read()   ###source: ubuntuforums.org###
    print opentxt    ###opentxt being the contents of sample.txt###

    
    converted=[ord(c) for c in opentxt]   ###conversion of text into a list of ascii###
    print converted
    

    
    offset_ADD=[s + offset_factor for s in converted]
```

I have gotten up to a point which I have created a list of ascii code based on the text file and added a randomly generated number to each of the ascii elements of the list. the task asks:

> Develop the part of the program that converts each character in the message into its ASCII code and encrypts it using the following rules:
>
> a. If the character is a space then do not encrypt the character
> b. otherwise:
> i. convert the character into its ASCII code (eg B = 66)
> ii. add the ASCII code to the offset factor calculated in Task 4. If the result is greater than 126 then subtract 94 so that the result is a valid ASCII code
> iii. convert the result into its equivalent ASCII character.

I have done part bi and half of bii but the other half of bii and biii I have problems with.

if the question is not clear enough please do ask to explain parts of the program.

This is when I execute the program:

```
1. Encrypt Message 2. Decrypt message 3. Quit
Please enter your selection 1
Option 1 selected
enter filename you want to encryptsample.txt
[35, 121, 52, 49, 63, 56, 58, 47]
#y41?8:/
28
Somewhere in la Mancha, in a place whose name I do not care to remember, a  gentleman lived not long ago, one of those who has a lance and ancient shield on a shelf and keeps a skinny nag and a greyhound for racing.
[83, 111, 109, 101, 119, 104, 101, 114, 101, 32, 105, 110, 32, 108, 97, 32, 77, 97, 110, 99, 104, 97, 44, 32, 105, 110, 32, 97, 32, 112, 108, 97, 99, 101, 32, 119, 104, 111, 115, 101, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 73, 32, 100, 111, 32, 110, 111, 116, 32, 99, 97, 114, 101, 32, 116, 111, 32, 114, 101, 109, 101, 109, 98, 101, 114, 44, 32, 97, 32, 103, 101, 110, 116, 108, 101, 109, 97, 110, 32, 108, 105, 118, 101, 100, 32, 110, 111, 116, 32, 108, 111, 110, 103, 32, 97, 103, 111, 44, 32, 111, 110, 101, 32, 111, 102, 32, 116, 104, 111, 115, 101, 32, 119, 104, 111, 32, 104, 97, 115, 32, 97, 32, 108, 97, 110, 99, 101, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 97, 110, 99, 105, 101, 110, 116, 32, 115, 104, 105, 101, 108, 100, 32, 111, 110, 32, 97, 32, 115, 104, 101, 108, 102, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 107, 101, 101, 112, 115, 32, 97, 32, 115, 107, 105, 110, 110, 121, 32, 110, 97, 103, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 97, 32, 103, 114, 101, 121, 104, 111, 117, 110, 100, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 114, 97, 99, 105, 110, 103, 46]
```

Comment: So what are the problems you are having? Do you have a stack trace you can show us?

Comment: You may want to read [ask] (especially pay attention to _Help others reproduce the problem_), and rewrite/amend your question accordingly.